# An error while converting string into float in a CSV file

Tags: python, csv

I have created a CSV (Comma delimited) file from an Excel file. I would like to analyze them in Python (ver. 3.5) using Spyder.

I managed to create nice lists from the CSV file I've mentioned above. My next goal is to convert the **strings** into **floats** so that I would be able to do some calculations using them. However an error occurred and I have no idea how can I deal with it.

This is the error message:
[image: Error Message]

Here's my code:

```
import pandas
colnames = ['GDP', 'Unemployment', 'CPI', 'HousePricing']
data = pandas.read_csv('C:/PATH.csv', 
                       names = colnames, header=None, sep=';')
GDP = data.GDP.tolist()
data['GDP'] = data['GDP'].astype(float)
print(GDP)
```

That's how my CSV file looks like:
[image: CSV file]

I would really appreciate any help or tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
data['GDP'] = data['GDP'].str.replace(",", ".").astype(float)
```

You are getting the error because of comma. Replacing it with dot should fix your issue.

**Demo:**

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'GDP': ["1,21", "2.2", "3,4", "5,66", "77,09"]})
print df['GDP'].str.replace(",", ".").astype(float)
```

**Output:**

```
0     1.21
1     2.20
2     3.40
3     5.66
4    77.09
Name: GDP, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Unfortunately this method does not work. There is no error however but the records are still strings.